# Angular-ui bootstrap accordion - cant disable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an accordion from angular-ui bootstrap. In the header of **each** accordion i have a checkbox that should enable/disable the ability to open the accordion. 
Heres the code

```
<div ng-repeat="b in board | filter:searchText track by b.Id">
<accordion-group class="animation-appear" ng-disabled="b.selected">
    <accordion-heading>
        <h4>
            {{b.Name}} <small>- set list aliases</small>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="b.selected" ng-model="b.selected" ng-click="checkboxClick(b, $event)" style="float:right" />
        </h4>
    </accordion-heading>
        ....
        ....
        ....
</accordion-group>
```

Everything seems to work fine, except the ability to disable an accordion. The accordions work, the checkboxes in the accordions work, the model from $scope.board.selected is updated, but still the ng-disabled doesnt disable the accordion

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in the latest released version (0.10.0) but the new release (coming this weekend!) has a support for the `is-disabled` property. See https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/9c43ae7c0a66ff454c97296122d8f82c89ac4d5e

You can build content of the https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap repo if you need this support now.